# What exactly is "the stack" in CPython?

Tags: python, stack, cpython

I'm trying to understand memory management in CPython but I don't fully understand the following terms: runtime stack, stack memory space, and stack data structure. I have a basic idea in what these terms mean but I don't fully understand their relationship. I mean, is the runtime stack a stack data structure, which lives on the stack memory space? Or are all three terms mutually exclusive?

I've read that all objects go on the heap space, but the VM is "stack-based". Does this mean that "something" lives on the memory stack space?

Comment: I believe you could get a better understanding of how CPython virtual machine works if you studied the basics of stack-based virtual machines. That basically all it is.

Comment: Thanks! I'll research that.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend looking into a course called _[CPython internals: A ten-hour codewalk through the Python interpreter source code](http://pgbovine.net/cpython-internals.htm)_ to get a better overall understaind of how CPython operates.

Comment: The linked duplicate answers one of your question's questions. Please only ask one question per question. I recommend doing some more independent research into these terms, as this site isn't a tutoring service.